# Cómo utilizar los static files para plantilla de correo?

Tags: django, django-templates

Estoy mandando un correo a los usuarios cuando se registran para que puedan activar sus cuentas con el siguiente código que se encuentra en el método `form_valid` de la vista:

```
current_site = get_current_site(self.request)
subject = 'Activate your account'
message = render_to_string('accounts/mails/account_activation_email.html', {
    'user': user,
    'domain': current_site.domain,
    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
})

html_message = get_template('accounts/mails/account_activation_email.html').render({
    'user': user,
    'domain': current_site.domain,
    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
})
user.email_user(subject, message, html_message=html_message)
```

Esta es mi plantilla `account_activation_email.html`:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://{{ domain }}{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
        }

        .text-center img {
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 150px;
        }

        .col-12.body {
            border-top: 3px solid #b70553;
            margin-top: 15px;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 15px;
        }

        .logo-color {
            color: #b70553;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img src="https://{{ domain }}{% static 'img/logo.svg' %}" alt="BCC">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 body">
                Dear {{ user }},

                Welcome to <span class="logo-color">AwesomeSite</span>!

                Your registration was successful and your user information have been saved.

                Please confirm your email address by clicking on the following link:
                http://{{ domain }}{% url 'accounts:activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}

                Once you confirmed your email address, your account will be active.

                You have now the opportunity to become a customer or an Affiliate.

                Please find more info upon login into your backoffice.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://{{ domain }}{% static 'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://{{ domain }}{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

La questión es que me está cargando los estilos que tengo escritos en ese template, pero las clases de bootstrap no las está cargando. Cómo puedo arreglar esto?

Comment: No es necesario `https://{{ domain }}`, en el `href`, basta con poner  `{% static '...' %}`. Intenta cambiando eso haber que sucede.

Comment: @JulioCesar ya lo probé y nada

Comment: Entonces la ruta esta mal o tu configuración de archivos staticos están mal, edita tu pregunta adjuntando el código de tu configuración de archivos staticos(`settings.py`).